# How to combine several similar terms in computation of algebra?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

As the title shows, how can I combine several similar terms when I try to compute some complex algebra terms. For example, I want the result of $$\frac{1}{6} b_1 \left(-\left(b_2^2 \left(-2 \sqrt{3} e^{-3 i \theta _1}+\left(\sqrt{3}-3 i\right) e^{-3 i \theta _2}+3 i+\sqrt{3}\right)\right)+2 \sqrt{3} b_3 b_2 \left(2 e^{-3 i \theta _1}+2 e^{-3 i \theta _2}+3 e^{-i \left(\theta _1+\theta _2\right)}+2\right)+b_3^2 \left(2 \sqrt{3} e^{-3 i \theta _1}-\left(\sqrt{3}+3 i\right) e^{-3 i \theta _2}+3 i-\sqrt{3}\right)\right)$$ to be collected by $b_1b_2b_3$, and obviously, the term $b_1b_2b_3$ in the above formula is not collected together. I've tried `Collect` function while I still cannot get the wanted form. Is there some method I can collect terms in the form $b_ib_jb_k$?

For your convenience, I attach the mathematica code for the formula as follows:

```
(1/6)*Subscript[b, 
  1]*(-((3*I + 
        Sqrt[3] - (2*Sqrt[3])/
         E^(3*I*Subscript[\[Theta], 1]) + (-3*I + Sqrt[3])/
         E^(3*I*Subscript[\[Theta], 2]))*Subscript[b, 2]^2) + 
      2*Sqrt[
     3]*(2 + 2/E^(3*I*Subscript[\[Theta], 1]) + 
      2/E^(3*I*Subscript[\[Theta], 2]) + 
      3/E^(I*(Subscript[\[Theta], 1] + Subscript[\[Theta], 2])))*
    Subscript[b, 2]*Subscript[b, 3] + 
      (3*I - 
      Sqrt[3] + (2*Sqrt[3])/
       E^(3*I*Subscript[\[Theta], 1]) - (3*I + Sqrt[3])/
       E^(3*I*Subscript[\[Theta], 2]))*Subscript[b, 3]^2)
```

Comment: I assume that you mean by "to be collected by  b1b2b3" that you want the coefficient of b1 b2 b3, considering the expression as polynomial in bi. This can be done by the function "Coefficient"

Comment: Something like `Activate@Expand@Collect[expr, Subscript[b, _], Inactive]`, where `expr` is your expression?